# How to make Celery waiting for a specific delay before executing a new task

Tags: python, redis, rabbitmq, celery, celery-task

I am using Celery to parallelize the execution of a Python function calling a third-party API.

This API imposes to wait for at least 3 seconds between each call.

Is there a way to specify a Message Broker (RabbitMQ or Redis) to respect this delay between each worker call ?

Answer (score 1):

In Celery, you can use the countdown method.  See https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown

RabbitMQ has a few different options for supporting delayed messages including the delayed message exchange plugin and dead lettering.  Unfortunately, Celery doesn't support either of these methods.  What it does instead is delay execution of the message until the countdown time is reached.  The message itself is immediately sent to the worker.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Unfortunately, I fear none of the proposed solutions offer what I am looking for. I want my whole pool of workers to respect a delay of 3 seconds between the start of the execution of each task.

The countdown or delayed message delay the sending of a specific task into the task queue. In my case, as the tasks take approximately 16 seconds in average, the countdown would not be of any help. Even with the 3s countdown, the tasks would stack in the task queue.

Dead lettering is about retrying the publishing of a message in case of failure.

Answer (score 0):

Would check out https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#retrying

Specify the retry delay to be 3 seconds and you can set a limit for the number of retries to be X as part of the task definition as seen in the docs.

Comment: Thanks for replying but this is not what I am looking for : I want my whole pool of workers to respect a delay of 3 seconds between the start of the execution of each task